# Excel programming reference cells for fantasy draft

Tags: excel, reference, cell

I want to display the results team by team for a fantasy draft. I created a data validation so that each team can be selected and dropped down. I tried using:

`IF ($B$36=Table2[[#Headers],[Turnin Two]],C2,""),IF($B$36=Table2[[#Headers],[The Agency]],D2,"")`

... and so on.

I first tried this as a single statement with the "value if false" being the next IF statement.

I want cell B37:B67 to display the same data as rows 2:32 for each respective column based on what cell B36 says.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THrxY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use **index()** and **match()** together:
(assuming row 1 contains the values to be matched by B36, and assuming data goes through column Z)

```
B37=INDEX(B2:Z32,MATCH(B$36,B1:Z1))
```

then copy down through B67

Comment: I tried this and it's getting closer. It isn't matching the exact column that the data from row one has beneath it. It is just giving me data from column b

Comment: It was also giving me a #REF when I put your formula in but I changed it to K32 and K1 respectively from Z32 and Z1. I put a comma before the last parenthesis and it that's when it gave me data but the wrong data as mentioned above. Thanks

Comment: try B37=INDEX(B2:Z32,MATCH(B$36,$B$1:$Z$1))

Comment: That gives me a #REF unless i put a comma before the last parenthesis but even doing that gives me incorrect data

Comment: this is hard without seeing your data `B37=INDEX(B2:Z2,MATCH(B$36,$B$1:$Z$1,0))`

Comment: Awesome that did it. Thanks alot